# Pandas once condition is met in column delete n rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [.8,.9,1,1,1,.9,1,.9,.8]})`.

The goal I have is once a number 1 in 'col1' is found, remove the next five rows.

**Example**

```
    col1
0   0.8
1   0.9
2   1.0
3   1.0
4   1.0
5   0.9
6   1.0
7   0.9
8   0.8
```

**Expected Output**

```
    col1
0   0.8
1   0.9
2   1.0
3   0.8
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [numpy.r_](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to generate the integers:

```
position_of_1 = np.argmax(df.col1.eq(1)) # df.col1.eq(1).idxmax() not fool-proof

integers = np.r_[: position_of_1 + 1, 
                 range(position_of_1 + 6, len(df))
                 ]

df.iloc[integers]


col1
0   0.8
1   0.9
2   1.0
8   0.8
```

Thanks to @Ben, for the suggestion on [np.argmax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html); it would be much better/safer to use np.argmax, for scenarios where the index are not numbers or not in proper form:

Comment: I see it is not working with df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [.8,.9,1,1,1,.9,1,.9,.8,.7,.6,.5,1,.4,.3,.5,.7,.9,.5,.4]})

Comment: @JohnsonFrancis. what should be the output.

Comment: Nice, but I would change `df.col1.eq(1).idxmax()` to `np.argmax(df.col1.eq(1))` to make this a little more bullet-proof. (Consider the case where `df`'s index is not 0, 1, 2, ...`

Comment: thanks @Ben, I'll edit now. That's a great suggestion

Comment: I believe, the requirement is to skip next 5 rows, when a '1' is found. So, if there are multiple '1's this code won't work. This code takes care of only the first '1' found.

Comment: ``once a number 1 is found skip the next 5 rows``,  ``everytime a number 1 is found, skip the next five rows``. two different statements. of course, I would allow the OP to clarify. I presented the answer based on my understanding of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I did something quickly...  May not look good.. but should work with multiple '1's in the df and discard the next 5 rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [.8,.9,1,1,1,.9,1,.9,.8,.7,.6,.5,1,.4,.3,.5,.7,.9,.5,.4]})
print(df)
idx_1=np.append(df[df.col1==1].index.values,len(df)-1)
i=0
idr=np.zeros(0)
for x in idx_1:
    if i <= x :
        idr=np.append(idr,np.r_[i:x+1])
        i=x+6
print(df.iloc[idr])
```

Input df

```
    col1
    0    0.8
    1    0.9
    2    1.0
    3    1.0
    4    1.0
    5    0.9
    6    1.0
    7    0.9
    8    0.8
    9    0.7
    10   0.6
    11   0.5
    12   1.0
    13   0.4
    14   0.3
    15   0.5
    16   0.7
    17   0.9
    18   0.5
    19   0.4
```

Output df :

```
    col1
    0    0.8
    1    0.9
    2    1.0
    8    0.8
    9    0.7
    10   0.6
    11   0.5
    12   1.0
    18   0.5
    19   0.4
```